# Xcode Native UITests very slow on real device

Tags: ios, xcode, performance, xcode-ui-testing, ui-testing

If I run my UITests on a simulator, they will run a lot faster, every interaction is faster somehow. Where a simulator takes about 20 seconds, a real device takes about 2 minutes.

It's like I watch a sloth tap the buttons on the real device.

Some info:

- Xcode 9.2
- Devices: iPhone 6 plus (iOS 10.1.1) and iPad Air (10.3.3)
- MacBook Pro (Retina, 15-inch, Mid 2015) with MacOS Sierra 10.12.6
- Swift 4
- Simulator: iPhone 6 (iOS 11.2)

I've noticed that an iPhone 6 plus running iOS 11.2.6 runs UITests significantly faster. It is not a performance issue, it's an idling issue.

Any ideas?

Comment: Is any of it explained in the WWDC 2017 video on UI testing performance? https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2017/409/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There were 2 things I needed to do

**Disable animations**

[image: Disable animations] .
This was the main thing, as the UITests were actually waiting for the app to idle (not in animating state) all the time. With UITests I want to check if the UI flow is still intact, not if view transition animations still work, that is the job of iOS itself.

**Switch to iOS 11+**
I noticed that iOS 11 was much faster than iOS 10.

After these changes the UITests were fast again :)